# Re-render page on clicking button even though dependency array object remains unchanged remains in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React 17.0.1. I am not able to figure out the following:

1. Page re-renders if the button is clicked multiple times even when the id remains unchanged.
2. Also I am encountering another error:   Line 25:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.
   I am guessing this error is caused due to the fact id is set outside of the render.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function DataFetcing() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
  const [id, setId] = useState(1);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(1);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(post);
    setSearch(post);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setPost(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setPost(err);
      });
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Fetch Post
      </button>
      <input type="text" value={id} onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)} />
      <span key={post.id}>{post.title}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DataFetcing;
```

Comment: You say "***even though dependency array object remains unchanged***" but it does not. You change the object each time you click because its time the axios is called it uses `setPost` which changes the `post`, which in turn will be used by the next `handleClick`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are using the `search` state for. But if you just want the component to fetch when someone hits the `Fetch Post` button I would maybe add a `searchId` state. This solves all the complexities with the `useEffect` hook. I understand that you want to have a controlled input and therefore need the `id` state. In this case it is not terrible to add an additional state variable specifically for the id that you use to fetch.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function DataFetcing() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
  const [id, setId] = useState(1);
  const [searchId, setSearchId] = useState(id)
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(1);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(post);
    setSearch(post);
    setSearchId(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${searchId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setPost(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setPost(err);
      });
  }, [searchId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Fetch Post
      </button>
      <input type="text" value={id} onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)} />
      <span key={post.id}>{post.title}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DataFetcing;
```

Answer (score 0):

- **1)** Your code fetches data every time button is clicked, because when you give `[search]` as a second argument to `useEffect()` you are asking React to execute `useEffect()` block every time `search` variable changes.

  You are using 'setSearch()' to set `search` value to an object, and even if the object's properties and corresponding values will be the same as before, the way javascript sees it, two objects will never be equal. You can test it and see that `console.log({} === {})` outputs `false`.

  So, since you use 'setSearch()' in your `handleClick()` function to set `search` value to object, every time button is clicked it automatically triggers `useEffect()` and fetches data.
- **2)** React sees that you use `id` variable inside of `useEffect()`, so it assumes you want this effect to run if `id` is updated. It does not how you are updating `id` variable and it tries to protect you from accidentally using old fetched data if, for example, in a few months you decide to add another way to modify `id` variable (maybe 'fetch next post' button on the bottom of the page).

  This is part of `useEffect()` usefulness - it does not matter HOW `id` changes, data will be fetched, so you do not have to remember to do things like `setSearch(Id)` manually, which 1) is easy to forget and 2) has kind of vague intent when somebody reads code for the first time.
- **Solution:** The most straightforward way I can think of to fix your code without more context is to change `handleClick()` function so it sets `search` to `id` (which will be a number) instead of `post` (which will be
  an object and always trigger `useEffect()` function, see **2)**...

```
    const handleClick = () => {
      console.log(post);
      setSearch(id);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic implies the following.

Initial values:

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({});
const [id, setId] = useState(1);
const [search, setSearch] = useState(1);
```

Values after first click (say: input is 2):

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({ /* post 2 response */ });
const [id, setId] = useState(2);
const [search, setSearch] = useState({});
```

Values after second click (input is again 2):

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({ /* post 2 response */ });
const [id, setId] = useState(2);
const [search, setSearch] = useState({ /* post 2 response */ });
```

As you can see, the state values are still changed.
A simplest solution to this would be to just call your fetch from the handleClick function (and ommit the `search` state altogether).

Comment: Most probably `search` will be `{ /* post 1 response */ }` after first click, since first post is fetched and saved as `post` on page load, before you click the button, unless you are very fast and click before request is fulfilled :) I find those super fast state changes are most difficult to keep in your head while developing React app.

And even after second, third, fourth click value will be considered changed, even if it is `{ /* post 2 response */ }` to `{ /* post 2 response */ }` as two objects are never equal in javascript (see my answer or just `console.log({} === {})`)